# How can i bypass form Validation with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I bypass this validation in order to not see this alert : `alert('The provided zipvcode ' + zip + ' does not belong in ' + state );`
I used to have states as initial like exp Illinois = IL and now I do have them numeric Illinois = 01, my code is on a platform which has 500+ forms and only 10 of them need to have state value numeric so I was thinking on bypassing the validation, does that make sense ?

Thanks,

```
            function validate_zip_state() {
                // Get the zip
                var zip = $('#postal_code').val();
                // Get the state
                var state = $('#state option:selected').val();
                // Regex exp for zip formatting
                var the_exp = /^\d{5}$|^\d{5}-\d{4}$/;
                //var the_exp_state = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}$/;
                if( ! the_exp.test(zip) ) {
                    return false;
                }
                if(state != '') {   
                    var return_val = '';


                        {   
                            zip: zip, 
                            state: state 
                        },
                        function(data) {
                            if(data == '0') {
                                alert('The provided zipcode ' + zip + ' does not belong in ' + state );

                                return false;   
                            } else {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
```

So here is what i did myself is i manage to disable alert on the form 
by doing `function alert() { }`

but that will disable all alert on my form and i would like only to disable the alert related to that code

Comment: There is definitely something wrong in your code under the `var return_val = '';` line.

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried?

Comment: i didn't try anything because i couldn't find a solution :/ am seeking ideas am not looking for a ready solution

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes i added function alert() { } to my js code and it disable all alert on my validation but i want to be specific specially because i have other validation i need them to work